# django admin page is giving me 500 error in production

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am trying to setup django admin page for my site. for my local dev server it is working now fine, but once i pushed the code to server, and tried to open the admin page, it is giving me 500 error page.

i saw the traceback, it is saying: `DoesNotExist: Site matching query does not exist.`

but I dont know why and what is happening here. this is the whole traceback,

http://pastebin.com/QCdGWTDq

can someone please help me?

Comment: Does your django.fcgi file add your root folder to the system path? e.g. `path = '/var/www/django/'` `if path not in sys.path:` `sys.path.insert(0, path)` The idea is that it should find your site's directory at this path (e.g. `/var/www/django/mysite/`)

Comment: the rest of the page is working, but only admin is not working. @pztrick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a `Site` object via Django shell on production site:

```
$ python manage.py shell
>>> from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
>>> Site.objects.create(domain='example.com', name='example.com')
```

Where `example.com` corresponds to your site's domain name used in production.

Normally a default `Site` object should be automatically created when you run the `syncdb` command, but I myself encountered cases when that didn't happen for some reason.

- See also: [Django's “sites” framework documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/#enabling-the-sites-framework)

Comment: wow, perfect! now working like a charm. i didnot know that ``Sites`` is thought for that ``example.com``. nice. thanks alot

Comment: but, one more thing. once i log into admin, it is deleting other session ids? why is this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Looks like an unrelated issue anyway, maybe you'd be better off creating another question for it.